# In linux kernel programming, use <mach/xxx.h>, where can I configure the "mach"

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

In arch/arm, there are a lot of "mach-xxx" folders, each one has include/mach/xxx.h headers, where is the configuration of "mach-xxx".

Comment: What linux version?  In older Linux (before device tree), these were used to statically configure some drivers/functions.  However, the Linux 'distro' people (Debian, Ubuntu, RedHat, etc) didn't like this as they had a separate kernel for each and every ARM system.  Device tree gets rid of this and everything is done dynamically (usually).  If performance is critical, a function pointer (like C++ virtuals) is used.

Comment: @artlessnoise Linux 2.6, ARM.